# Eclipse Declaration shortcut key F3 can not work in mac os

Tags: eclipse, macos

The Declaration shortcut key F3 seems not work in eclipse indigo at mac os  10.7.3,
it always show the dashboard and desktop chose interface.
and i try the ctrl+F3 and command+F3 always not work.
and the ctrl+click is the right key in my system, i don't want to change it.
I think maybe it's the key setting issue, but i have no idea about it.
Could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks.
can change this shortcut key to F3?

Comment: it doesn't work fn+F3 in MacOS v10.12.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using fn + F3 should do the trick

If you'd like to make all the function keys default to their standard behavior and instead press "fn + F3" for the OS X specific feature shortcut you can go to:

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard
```

and check the

```
"Use all F1,F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" box
```

Comment: can I change it to the F3 only?